# Jquery under png image mouse move?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

my problem is this link

[Sample Link](http://hayalhane.net/drag_and_drop/)

One image is puzzle,
Second image is earth,

I'am rotateable, dragable, and resize earth it's worked but front of the puzzle,

Sample image is puzzle,front of the earth I'am not touch earth, dragable or rotateable...

How's solution this problem I want to move earth, but front of puzzle image... Please help..

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what is the compatibility required, but this might help you

```
  <div style="position:absolute;width:430px;min-height:320px;z-index:2;background:url(images/15b.png);pointer-events:none">        
  </div>
```

Check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to see browsers support.